# How to move a job to another queue in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My job is already running, but I want move it to another queue without restarting the job, which command I can use to do this?

Comment: what scheduler are you using?

Comment: I just use the default scheduler of hadoop mapreduce framework

Answer (score 2):

For Hadoop 2.x distriutions, the following command may work:

```
yarn application -movetoqueue <application id> -queue <queue name>
```